# How do you encrypt a USB drive partition with the Twofish cipher and SHA-512 hash without using TrueCrypt?

Tags: security, encryption, luks, truecrypt, cryptsetup

I've been trying to string together the right flags in cryptsetup:

```
cryptsetup -y -h sha512 -c twofish-xts-plain64 -s 512 luksFormat /dev/sdx
```

But it hasn't been working. When I enter the command listed above, nothing happens; it doesn't even prompt me for a password. Trying this command with aes-xts-plain64 doesn't work either. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong? Or maybe there's a different program I could try. At this point I'd be willing to try anything.

Comment: Why do you want to use Twofish specifically? What error messages, if any, are you getting? In what way is the outcome not what you expect? Does your kernel support twofish in the first place? *Be specific.*

Comment: I don't see any error messages. When I enter the code I posted, nothing happens. It doesn't even prompt me for a password. And I'm not sure if my kernel supports Twofish.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include additional information requested in comments. Checking /proc/crypto will tell you if the kernel supports Twofish. And you still aren't answering the big question, why do you want to use *Twofish* rather than something else? Is there some particular reason why you don't want to use, say, AES-XTS, and if so then what is it?

Comment: I've edited the question to add more information. Thank you.

Comment: @SubtleArray not enough. you've ignored the most important question, as stated by multiple people. in any case, you found the solution, so I guess it doesn't matter.

Comment: @strugee You're right. It doesn't matter, and it never did matter. A simple mention of eCryptfs would have answered this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little help from [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/encryption/comments/26xodt/how_do_you_encrypt_a_usb_drive_partition_with_the/chviddp), I've figured it out.

[tcplay](https://github.com/bwalex/tc-play) did the trick. It encrypted my USB flash drive with the following command:

```
tcplay -c -d /dev/sdx -a SHA512 -b TWOFISH-256-XTS
```

tcplay is essentially a TrueCrypt clone. It's  available in the Ubuntu repositories. -c tells tcplay to create a new volume. -d specifies device. -a specifies hash. -b specifies cipher.

If tcplay gives you problems, you can use the eCryptfs.

[Here's a helpful tutorial](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-encrypt-directories-partitions-with-ecryptfs-on-debian-squeeze).